# How I delete an Inventory Item using the NetSuite API?

Tags: php, netsuite

I want to know if I can delete an InventoryItem through the API and what is the correct type id and of course if the code is correct.

This is my php code

```
    $deleteItem = new CustomRecordRef();
    $deleteItem->typeId = "inventoryitem";
    $deleteItem->internalId = 3237;
    //$deleteItem->name = "ssllrgrwb1";

    $delete = new DeleteRequest();
    $delete->baseRef = $deleteItem;

    $service = new NetSuiteService();
    $delResponse = $service->delete($delete);
```

This is the respond

```
DeleteResponse Object
(
    [writeResponse] => WriteResponse Object
        (
            [status] => Status Object
                (
                    [statusDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => StatusDetail Object
                                (
                                    [code] => INVALID_RCRD_TYPE
                                    [message] => Invalid Record Type
                                    [type] => ERROR
                                )

                        )

                    [isSuccess] => 
                )

            [baseRef] => CustomRecordRef Object
                (
                    [internalId] => 3237
                    [externalId] => 
                    [typeId] => inventoryitem
                    [name] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
$deleteItem = new RecordRef();
```